# I'm currently trying to create a Python Tkinter program where I utilise frames as page flips within a class

Tags: python, tkinter

Good Afternoon,

I'm currently having a play around with Tkinter and I am trying to make something that would symbolise a iPad page flip for an example I'm trying to use frames. In my example code below my plan is when the "Keyboard" button is pressed it hides frame1 & shows frame2. I'm trying to use the frame1.pack_forget command however as frame1 is defined  in another function it isn't currently working. Is there a way around or this or a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?
The code is a small work in progress from the actual script so I'm aware every "KeyboardBtns" will call the exact same function.

Thanks in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import SUNKEN

Keyboard = ["Source 1", "Source 2", "Source 3", "Source 4", "Source 5", "Source 6", "Source 7", "Source 8"]
# window = tk.Tk()


class GUI (tk.Tk):
    pass
    def __init__(self):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("700x700")




        frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Frame", relief= SUNKEN)
        frame1.pack()
        for i in range (len(Keyboard)):
            KeyboardBtns = tk.Button(frame1, width = 8, height = 1, text = Keyboard[i], command= lambda x = i: self.Test())
            KeyboardBtns.pack()


    def Test(self):
        frame1.pack_forget()
        frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self)
        b = tk.Button(frame2)
        frame2.pack()
        b.pack()


    def Run(self):
        self.mainloop()
       


GUI().Run()
```

Comment: Replace `frame1` with `self.frame1`. You have to do that on these lines: `frame1 = tk.LabelFrame()`, `frame1.pack()`, and `frame1.pack_forget()`

Comment: You should use self like self.frame1 and self.frame2. You won't have any problems then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your frame objects are not class members.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import SUNKEN

Keyboard = ["Source 1", "Source 2", "Source 3", "Source 4", "Source 5", "Source 6", "Source 7", "Source 8"]
# window = tk.Tk()


class GUI (tk.Tk):
    pass
    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("700x700")




        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Frame", relief= SUNKEN)
        self.frame1.pack()
        for i in range (len(Keyboard)):
            KeyboardBtns = tk.Button(self.frame1, width = 8, height = 1, text = Keyboard[i], command= lambda x = i: self.Test())
            KeyboardBtns.pack()


    def Test(self):
        self.frame1.pack_forget()
        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self)
        b = tk.Button(self.frame2)
        self.frame2.pack()
        b.pack()


    def Run(self):
        self.mainloop()



GUI().Run()
```